# Modx revo.2 contexts and Gallery.Gallery dont work in second context

Tags: gallery, modx, modx-revolution

I have a website on modx with 2 contexts.There is a template where was included Gallery plugin. The problem is that the plugin can not properly load the image in the second context.But in the web context images loaded normally.
Does anyone have the same problem,any ideas?

Comment: can you show the displayed image path by gallery in the html?

Comment: Yes, of course.
`/assets/components/gallery/connector.php?action=web/phpthumb&ctx=eng&w=57&h=57&zc=1&far=C&q=90&src=%2Fen%2F%2Fassets%2Fgallery%2F3%2F42.jpg`

Comment: And now i have one idea to fix it.In chunk `-gallerifficitemthumb.chunk.tpl` i use replace output filter
`href="[[+image:replace=`%2Fen%2F==%2F`]]"`, but it isnt best option =)

Comment: so is the output filter solution working? Can you also post the Link to the image file that is used in the other context?

Comment: Ok,i have 2 contexts:
1)web
2)eng 

in `web` link looks like `/assets/components/gallery/connector.php?action=web/phpthumb&ctx=eng&w=57&h=57&‌​zc=1&far=C&q=90&src=%2F%2Fassets%2Fgallery%2F3%2F42.jpg`

in `eng` link looks like `/assets/components/gallery/connector.php?action=web/phpthumb&ctx=eng&w=57&h=57&‌​zc=1&far=C&q=90&src=%2Fen%2F%2Fassets%2Fgallery%2F3%2F42.jpg`


pay attention to:
`%2Fen%2F%2Fassets%2Fgallery%2F3%2F42.jpg`
with filter i change `%2Fen%2F` to `%2F`.And it work=)

Comment: But there is a way to configure gallery to setup this path?I configure `gallery.files_path` and `gallery.files_url` it didnt help.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Just had to edit my old approach for that and thought I leave the way here.

I Simply duplicated the Gallery Snippet and edited the Line 119 to ...

`$itemArray['thumbnail'] = str_replace(array('%2Fdeutsch%2F','%2Fslo%2F','%2Fen%2F'),'',$item->get('thumbnail',$thumbProperties));`

... where deutsch, slo and en in the array are the context names. This should give you an idea how you could solve this permanantly in projects where you sometimes add or delete contexts.

Hope this helps someone! Have productive Day :)

**Old Answer**

Did you configured your .htaccess file correctly? (I guess you are using the Userfirendly URL Option)

A way to do so would be the following. In this example the contexts have the name of their language.

```
# redirect all requests from /[lang]/assets* to /assets*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(de|en|fr|it|ru|hu|pl)/assets(.*)$ assets$2 [L,QSA]
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer.But id didnt help me :(
i have the such code in my .htaccess file:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`


`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`


`RewriteRule ^(ru|en)/assets(.*)$ assets$2 [L,QSA]`

Comment: Excellent catch, I also had all the .htaccess rewrites but had this problem, the odd thing is that this started happening to me after 2.3.

Answer (score 0):

I used you fix today, Modx Revo 2.3.1

```
$itemArray['thumbnail'] = str_replace(array('%2Fen%2F'),'',$item->get('thumbnail',$thumbProperties));
$itemArray['image'] = str_replace(array('%2Fen%2F'),'',$item->get('image',$imageProperties));
```

This is for english context, en, but en it´s not the context name, it´s the lexicon value.

This fixed thumbs and large image, line 131.

Hope this help